# c# TextBox border changes when it gets disabled compared to other disabled TextBox(es)

Tags: c#, textbox, focus, border

I have a really strange problem.
I have multiple TextBoxes for username/passwords, and a CheckBox beside every user/pass group. When user clicks on the CheckBox, and if he checked it, the username and password TextBox beside it become enabled and focus is set to username TextBox. If user unchecked the CheckBox the TextBoxes beside it become disabled. However the border of one TextBox stays different than other disabled TextBoxes.

See:

[image: http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/1944/textbox.png]

I've thought it was a focus problem, so I've changed the code - when user unchecks the CheckBox it first focuses on some other element on the form and then disables it, but it still does the same thing.
Any ideas on what could cause the problem?

Comment: Have you checked that the properties on all your checkboxes are the same and that one of them doesn't have a different style or something on it?

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained very well - it happens to all TextBoxes - on the one that has been focused before disabled(also all were made with the same properties - only exception are pass TextBoxes that have password char). When I disable auto-focus on the user TextBox and user doesn't click to focus/type in it, the CheckBox doesn't change border when disabled. That's why i thought it was a focus problem. But then I've added a test TextBox tbTest, and did tbTest.Focus(); and then disabling of the 2 TextBoxes but still got the same result.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, yes I misread it as one particular checkbox was causing issues. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I can tell, this is a bug in the way the system is rendering the control's disabled state.  I've created the following code to simulate this issue.  The code is a bit verbose but I made it so in order easily understand the logic flow.

I created a form, with :
4 textboxes named txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3 and txtBox4
4 checkboxes named chkBox1, chkBox2, chkBox3 and chkBox4

Set the Enabled property of each textbox to False (I did this at design time)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        chkBox1.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
        chkBox2.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
        chkBox3.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
        chkBox4.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
    }

    private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var chkBox = ((CheckBox)sender);
        var controlSet = chkBox.Name.Substring(6,1);
        var txtName = "txtBox" + controlSet;

        foreach (var txtBox in Controls.Cast<object>().Where(ctl => ((Control)ctl).Name == txtName).Select(ctl => ((TextBox)ctl))) {
            if (chkBox.Checked) {
                txtBox.Enabled = true;
                txtBox.Focus();
            }
            else {
                //The checkbox stole the focuse when it was clicked, so no need to change.
                txtBox.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now if you execute this code, you can check the checkboxes to enable the textbox with the same name prefix (1, 2, 3 or 4). This also sets the focus to the Textbox.  Now, if you disable a Textbox that has the focus, it shows up differently than other disabled Textboxes.

I tried all kinds of Refresh, Invalidate, etc.. on the controls and Form itself to no avail.

**UPDATE**

So I found a hack that seems to work.  If you set the borderstyle of the textbox to 'None' before disabling, and then reset it afterwards, the odd outline effect doesn't happen.

```
    var borderStyle = txtBox.BorderStyle;
    txtBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    txtBox.Enabled = false;
    txtBox.BorderStyle = borderStyle;
```

Comment: I think I discovered that if you put a MessageBox.Show("something") in the comment line, after clicking ok the disable code will execute and TextBox will be like it should be.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a legitimate bug. Like I said, I tried to refresh/redraw the control to no avail.  I doubt you want to pop up a message box to fix the rendering of a control. Hope you figure something out. I'll play around with it some more this afternoon.

Comment: I found that if you make the form re-sizeable, and then re-size the form so that the textbox with the bad format isn't shown, then size the form back to normal, the format is correct. However, it doesn't work in code. You can also minimize and restore and it's back to what it should be.

Comment: Think I'm onto something. If you do a this.Refresh() for a form after the checkbox has been unchecked the other textboxes are refreshed and borders are normal, but still the last focused isn't. This can be solved by starting a timer or doing that with a delay, but delay depends on system speed. Is there a way of knowing when textbox has repainted, so there's no need for inheriting textbox class and overriding paint method?

Comment: It's even worse: The problem also occurs if a parent control is disabled. And then there's no chance to fix it properly.