# Problem with Disabled Textbox which had focus before it was disabled

Tags: vb.net, textbox, visual-studio-2017

I have Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2017 (Visual Basic).

I have a group box with two radio buttons and two text boxes. When `radiobutton1` is checked the two text boxes are not available (`Textbox.Enabled = false`).

[image: disabledTextboxes]

When the user hits `radiobutton2` the two text boxes are set to `enabled = true` and the first text box gets the focus with `textbox1.focus()`.

[image: enabledTextboxes, Textbox1.focus()]

when the user doesn't enter any value and hits the radiobutton1 the two textboxes are set to enabled = false again.

When you do that, the disabled `textbox1` looks different (inset) to `textbox2` because it had the focus before it was disabled.

[image: disabledTextbox1 looks different]

When `radiobutton2` is checked and you fill in, for example, `numvalues` to the text boxes and you use the enter button to validate both text boxes, there is no focus on the text boxes anymore. When you now hit `radiobutton1` both disabled text boxes are looking the same.

What event can I use to take away the focus of the text box (which has the focus) before I hit the `radiobutton1`?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you have noticed this is just a redrawing glitch that happens when you disable a focused textbox and it shouldn't be anything to worry about. However if you want to get rid of it, try giving focus to another control by calling the [`Control.Focus()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus) _before_ disabling your textbox. If that doesn't work also try calling `Refresh()` on your textbox to force it to redraw itself before disabling.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7905184/2505186

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved.

because i had no other control to give the focus to 
i created a label with the width of 0 so one can't see the IBeam cursor.

For radiobutton1 i created a mouseenter and a mouseleave event.
when the mouse is over radiobutton1 the "hidden" label gets the focus. when the mouse leaves radiobutton1 the textbox1 gets the focus again.

the refresh() method didn't help.

Thx for your comment Visual Vincent!

p.s.: i don't know why but only setting the focus to the label without using the mouse events didn't solve the problem!

Comment: This is somewhat peculiar. If you haven't notice (easy to miss), when a TextBox loses the Focus, its Focus Border is not repainted immediately: it *gracefully fades* to light gray. You can make this really visible if you use a CheckBox to change the Enabled state of the TextBox (RadioButtons and Focus is another thing), make its `CheckedChanged` event `async`. After you set the `TextBox.Enabled` property to false, insert `await Task.Delay(300)` and `TextBox.Refresh()`. You'll see that the border suddenly changes to the default *disabled* color. You could also paint it yourself...

Comment: @Jimi, I haven't noticed :) But what you wrote is very interesting. Thx for the details!

Comment: Glad you got it working! But couldn't you just give focus to the radio button itself instead? Seems unnecessary to add another control just to switch focus. :)

Comment: That was my first idea too. But giving the focus to the radiobutton didn't fix it. what helped too was a second mouse click on radiobutton2 while it is checked. That takes the focus completely away of the textbox too. but that would be a solution only for me and not for any other user.